# Get the position of icons on the desktop

Tags: cocoa, macos

How can I get the position of an icon on the desktop in OS X? Or, how can I get a list of all icons on the desktop and their positions?

Answer (score 4):

Try this AppleScript code

```
tell application "Finder"
    get desktop position of every item of desktop
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for a folder is to [use a catalog iterator](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSGetCatalogInfoBulk) to get the Finder info for every item in the folder. The Finder info is a [FileInfo](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Finder_Interface/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/FileInfo) or [FolderInfo](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Finder_Interface/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/FolderInfo) structure that contains a QuickDraw `Point` (integral co-ordinates, origin top-left, positive y down) specifying where the icon will appear.

I don't know how you would do this for the Desktop, though. There is a Desktop folder in the Home folder, but examining its contents will probably get you the positions that the Finder will use to display that folder in a window. It also will probably not include anything “on the Desktop” that isn't in the Desktop folder, such as mounted volumes.

Answer (score 0):

following apple script will get those positions (use either scripting bridge or NSAppleScript)

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell every item of desktop
        get position
        get name
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: sorry, there was a hard-coded path pointing to my desktop. fixed it by pointing to "of desktop"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (Very similar to the one of @Vaskravchuk)

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with anItem in desktop
        get {desktop position, name} of anItem
    end repeat
end tell
```