# Sorting the icons on Desktop using Swift and Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager, nsworkspace

After mounting my Volumes, I want them sorted by name on the Desktop.

How can I do this with Cocoa and Swift?

Comment: Not sure if Cocoa has that ability.

Comment: Have a look at AppleScript. I know you can [get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845420/get-the-position-of-icons-on-the-desktop) the icons positions, so maybe you can also set them.

Comment: That is a good idea. If it works, i can that also implement into my app. Thx